# Stop iPhone 11 Screen Recording from Cutting off Automatically

Tags: ios, screen, recording

I’m trying to record something on my iPhone 11 and it keeps stopping every few minutes. Is there a way to keep this from happening so I can get the full recording?

Is this caused by screen going dark or something else I could fix?

Comment: Which version of iOS?  How much memory do you have left?  After how many minutes does it cut off?

Comment: Probably a storage "issue". Could you check how much you have left in *Settings > General > iPhone storage*?

Comment: ios 16.5.1 -- storage still at 1/2 capacity. Sorry my polite, friendly message was edited.  Can't imagine why that was necessary!?! When it happened, the best communication would have been to offer a polite explanation!